# How to Mock an external API that an internal API calls?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, integration, micronaut

I am having trouble on how to Mock an external API that an internal API calls.
What I want is basically to test the call on the internal API, to see if it reaches the point of the external API path. I am using Mockito with java and can't seem to get it working. I want to intercept the External API call and return a mock response so the external api isn't hit. 
Here is what I have tried:
I am using Micronaut using HttpClients in my tests to do something like:

`HttpResponse<blah> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, blah.class);`
, which is the internal API call. The external api call is in the form of:

`HttpResponse<blah> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, blah.class, error.class);`

I am trying to catch the external API call in my Integration test class by:
`when(client.toBlocking().exchange(any(MutableHttpRequest.class), any(Argument.class), any(Argument.class))).thenReturn(resp);`

But it seems like I cannot even reach the internal api, the call never seems to be made. I believe that it is being intercepted earlier.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated - I am not sure if this is the right approach or if there's some easier way, but thank you in advance.

Comment: You're trying to mock too many layers at once.  You'd need to _first_ mock the result of `client.toBlocking()`.  And then have _that_ mock have a mocked `exchange` method.

Comment: Or you can use the `RETURN_DEEP_STUBS` option, which basically does that part for you. However if you are a beginner with mockito, I suggest you use @BeUndead's suggestion to get a better understanding of the basic concepts.

Comment: @second: I did consider that.  Unfortunately I think it would take the same amount of work, since you need to control the return of one of those deep stubs.